# Программы для просмотра изображений

Tags: reverse-engineering

Занимаюсь распаковкой игры "IGI 2:Covert Strike". (Reverse Enginering)
Естественно встретил множество нестандартных форматов.
В частности форматов изображении, текстур, битмапов и.т.д.

Ковырять их python-ом и выводить на экран с помощью pillow, довольно затратно по времени, неудобно и (самое важное) пространства для манёвра очень мало.

Есть ли какой нибудь софт позволяющий вольно интерпретировать битмапы.
Например очередь каналов, формат упаковки пикселя, соотношения сторон и.т.д.

Или идеи какие.
Спасибо.

Comment: По поводу Python и Pillow - как-то экспериментировал с извлечением ресурсов из одной игры для ZX Spectrum, очень помогает Jupyter в этом случае - можно быстро поменять параметры, и сразу увидеть результат.

Comment: [Например](https://gist.github.com/insolor/e30e41b333707a9b6869a7c73881f554)

Comment: Ну и чисто для просмотра IrfanView: Файл - Открыть как - RAW-файл. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SbZp.png Но Jupyter Notebook в итоге все равно удобнее.

Comment: Может `StegSolve.jar` найдет тут применение.